# Merge repeated values into a field in a Dataframe with scala and spark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a DF like following :

```
ID  hier    
1   Z1  
1   Z2      
2   Z1
2   Z2
```

and the output required is a DF like the next :

```
ID  hier    
1   Z1,Z2   
2   Z1,Z2
```

Im know about the Fold and reduce but I dont have very clear how use that for this case .

Answer (score 1):

`Fold` and `Reduce` are functional methods. Working with `DataFrames` provides a relational algebra to express your transformations. You should consider using the `collect_list` built-in function for your question :

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    import spark.implicits._

    val df = Seq(
      (1,"Z1"),
      (1,"Z2"),
      (2,"Z1"),
      (2,"Z2")
    ).toDF("ID", "hier")

    df.groupBy($"ID").agg(collect_list($"hier").as("hier"))
      .show(false)

+---+------------------+
|ID |hier              |
+---+------------------+
|2  |[Z1, Z2]          |
|1  |[Z1, Z2]          |
+---+------------------+
```

And if you want a String, you can use this transformation instead :

```
df.groupBy($"ID").agg(concat_ws(",",collect_list($"hier")).as("hier"))

+---+-----+
|ID |hier |
+---+-----+
|2  |Z1,Z2|
|1  |Z1,Z2|
+---+-----+
```